# what's the parameters' usage in detail of SHA1() function in c language

Tags: c++, c, cryptography, sha1

For example, I've seen a file like this:

```
char data[] = "Hello, world!";

size_t length = sizeof(data);

unsigned char hash[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];

SHA1(data, length, hash);
```

Then, I found a instance almost like it. However the difference is `SHA1(data, length - 1, hash);` So, I am a little confused. Should I use `"sizeof(data)"` or `"sizeof(data)-1"`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @bot, Thanks for your kindness, things is that I want to hash more than one string like "hello, world", and then concatenate the hashed strings to a longer string, and then convert the longer string to some specific element type. when I do that, I used some functions with similar parameters as the "length" and buffer, like snprintf() etc. so I found that I need understand any parameters' meaning, so my question might be a little bit idiot... anyway. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the actual payload you want to hash.

- `sizeof data` includes the zero terminator.
- `sizeof(data) -1` or `strlen(data)` exclude the zero.

Comment: @bot, Thanks for your kindness, things is that I want to hash more than one string like "hello, world", and then concatenate the hashed strings to a longer string, and then convert the longer string to some specific element type. when I do that, I used some functions with similar parameters as the "length" and buffer, like snprintf() etc. so I found that I need understand any parameters' meaning, so my question might be a little bit idiot... anyway. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `SHA1` function takes byte length, it does not care it is c-string or not. So the parameter really means how many bytes to hash. Note the sizeof(data) in your example gives 14 while there is 13 visible characters.

Comment: Ok, Thanks very much, I understand what you say. However, when I get the hashed string named "hash" in the above, I got a 20-bytes(160 bits) long char string. actually, what I really want is a 160 bits 0-1 string(a string with only 0 and 1), I have no idea to work out the 0-1 string. Do you have an idea?

Comment: I remember the SHA1 function only cares about the 0-1 string as input